# extend beforeShow of jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How do I extend jQuery Datepicker 'beforeShow' function?

I was trying:

```
(function ($) {
    var old = $.fn.datepicker.beforeShow;
    $.fn.datepicker.beforeShow = function () {

        var ret = old.apply(this, arguments);
        alert("Extended functionality of beforeShow function!");



        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE:**

I'd like to add some extra functionality for all my datepickers like checking the css class; I think a good approach would be to extend the functionality of the `beforeShow` method rather than placing that functionality in each place.

Comment: Can u clearify little more??

Comment: @ShoaibChikate: I'd like to add some logic to beforeShow method for all my datepickers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery UI datepicker, use the [$.datepicker.setDefaults()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-functions) method.

E.g.:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    beforeShow: function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('test')) {
            alert('got ya');   
        }

    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vbLH3/)

**EDIT**

According to your comment I'd delegate a click event listener to the datepicker elements.
Otherwise you'll always overwrite the original property value.

```
$('.datepicker').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('test')) {
        alert('got ya');   
    }   
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function () {
        //Still called?
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vbLH3/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but this one gets called only if I haven't defined beforeShow method on the element